# Git : Ignore all file and directory but not some codes in subdirectory

Tags: git, gitignore

I create a git repository named `test_dir/` with git init,

in `test_dir`, I have some files and  a subdirectory named code as below.

```
$ ls test_dir/
a.dat  b.dat  code/  c.py

$ ls test_dir/code/
e.dat  f.dat  test2.py  test3.py  test.py
```

I want to create a `.gitignore` file to ignore all files but not the python script file (`*.py`) in git root directory and in its subdirectory.

How should I configure my `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like

```
*
!.gitignore
!*/
!**/*.py
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks work well!  If I have deeper structure of directories (such as `./code/code1/code2/...` , but have no idea how deep it is), how can I write the `.gitignore` for the same purpose?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, this `.gitignore` file should work for the deeper structure you described. You will see the `code/` on `git status` output if that structure has any `*.py` files in it.

Comment: Yes ! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `!` to escape from ignoring. For subdirectories `!*/`

Answer (score 0):

You can write two rules, one to ignore and the other to exclude. It should be something like this:

```
test_dir/code/*
!test_dir/code/*.py
```

Comment: Use `*` in .gitignore file. It ignores all files in the repo directory.